# giving effects to buttons in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

[image: Buttons on UI]

Image shows the buttons on my UI in vb.net
All these buttons are having background images. Now what i want is these buttons be shown as inactive when actions corresponding to them are not available so I am making them cmd.enable = false but still on UI there is no visual effect of this disabling them on these buttons. They keep looking same as in enabled mode. So how to give effect of disabled state to these buttons.

In the same way i want effect to be visible when mouse is hovered over these buttons and buttons are clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't look like buttons at all, it looks like a row of images.  Use a real Button or a ToolStrip with ToolStripButtons, set their Image property.  When you set their Enabled property to false then they automatically remove all color from the image, making it look disabled.